# Continuously reading output (StdOut) from Process in C#, accessing multiple times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, process, buffer, stdout

I'm running a process in C# that I want to run for basically the lifespan of my program. I am essentially trying to just create an interface where I can continuously send new inputs to the process and receive process outputs, and I need to do this multiple times. Flow is something like start the initial process, give command, receive + process output, give another command, receive + process more output, etc.

Currently the process output is going to StdOut. The problem I am running into is this isn't how StdOut works, as once I read from it, the Stream pointer is at the end, and new Process output doesn't get appended to the buffer, rather overwrites it and I cannot access it (I think this is how this works?). There doesn't seem to be a way for me to Seek() to rewind StdOut either. One other thing I thought of is instead redirecting the process output to a file, but can't seem to get that working either. What would be a good workaround to this? Here is some sample code:

```
    Process simulator;

    void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            simulator = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = NODE_PATH,
                    Arguments = "\"" + ARG_PATH + "\" \"command-to-open-interactive-process\""
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                }
            };
            simulator.Start();
            simulator.StandardInput.WriteLine("command1");
            ReadOutput();
            simulator.StandardInput.WriteLine("command2");
            ReadOutput();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(e.Message);
        }
    }

    public string EvokeResponse(string s)
    {
        FeedInput(s);
        return ReadOutput();
    }

    private void FeedInput(string s)
    {
        simulator.StandardInput.WriteLine(s);
    }

    private string ReadOutput()
    {
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        while (!OutputIsEmpty())
        {
            var line = simulator.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            response.Append(line);
        }
        return response.ToString();
    }

    private bool OutputIsEmpty()
    {
        return simulator.StandardOutput.Peek() <= -1;
    }
```

Comment: multithreading is not safe in unity, I suggest not using it

Answer (score 0):

As it stands currently this will most probably freeze your Unity application while you are waiting for output from the process.

Also currently you do nothing with your received results.

Indeed multithreading is tricky in Unity but nothing to be too scared about ;) You only need to have in mind that most of the Unity API can only be used by the Unity main thread. So you will have to synchronize the output back into the Unity main thread.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Thread thread;

    private class WorkPackage
    {
        public readonly string Message;
        public readonly Action<string> ReceiveCallback;

        public WorkPackage(string message, Action<string> receiveCallback)
        {
            Message = message;
            ReceiveCallback = receiveCallback;
        }
    }

    // Thread-safe queue (First in - First out) for the received messages
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<WorkPackage> receivedMessages = new ConcurrentQueue<WorkPackage>();

    // Thread-saf queue for the message to send
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<WorkPackage> messagesToSend = new ConcurrentQueue<WorkPackage>();

    // Wait handle to set when something shall be sent
    private readonly EventWaitHandle waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    private void Awake()
    {
        thread = new Thread(() => ProcessThread(waitHandle));
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        while (receivedMessages.TryDequeue(out var message))
        {
            message.ReceiveCallback?.Invoke(message.Message);
        }
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        thread?.Abort();
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message, Action<string> resultCallback)
    {
        var workPackage = new WorkPackage(message, resultCallback);
        messagesToSend.Enqueue(workPackage);
        waitHandle.Set();
    }

    private void ProcessThread(EventWaitHandle waitHandle)
    {
        Process simulator = null;

        try
        {
            simulator = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = NODE_PATH,
                    Arguments = "\"" + ARG_PATH + "\" \"command-to-open-interactive-process\""
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                }
            };
            simulator.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                // wait until there is a command to send
                waitHandle.WaitOne();

                // pick the first message from the thread-safe queue
                messagesToSend.TryDequeue(out var sendMessage);
                simulator.StandardInput.WriteLine(sendMessage);
                simulator.StandardInput.Flush();

                // wait until something is available
                while (simulator.StandardOutput.Peek() <= -1)
                {
                    // you can play around with this but you shouldn't make this too small
                    Thread.Sleep(50);
                }

                var response = new StringBuilder();
                // you might want to use a different approach here
                // Mainly I see two options for a proper protocol:
                //  - Either make your process beforehand send the amount of lines you have to receive
                //  - Use a certain termination line like e.g. "#%#%#%#%#%#%" so you know when you can finish receiving
                while (simulator.StandardOutput.Peek() > -1)
                {
                    var line = simulator.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                    response.Append(line);
                }

                var respondMessage = response.ToString();

                // dispatch this received message into the Unity main thread
                receivedMessages.Enqueue(new WorkPackage(respondMessage, sendMessage.ReceiveCallback));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogException(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            simulator?.Kill();
            simulator?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea to use threads for this as to not freeze my Unity editor. I am running into issues still with the thread halting though, specifically when using StdOut ReadLine / StdOut Peek. I think it's waiting for more output that doesn't come? Is there any way to push the thread along or better yet a reason you can see in your above code snippet what causes this to halt? @derHugo

Comment: @OGSuperSand I specifically designed it to hold the thread until there is a message to be sent .. then it holds until a message is received etc .... so its always one out one in .. assumed that was your described workflow ;)